# Write notes to piano roll on FL Studio while playing guitar via audio interface

Tags: audio-interfaces, fl-studio, guitar

I have guitar connected to computer via Scarlett 2i2 audio interface. I was wondering if is possible to **write notes directly to piano roll** on FL Studio 12 **while playing guitar**. I would like to try that if is possible, instead of buying MIDI keyboard.

Comment: This would require an audio to midi converter of some sort. something like.... https://www.widisoft.com/english/mp3-midi-products.html

Comment: @Mark WIDI Recognition System actually works!

Comment: Added a fuller answer - feel free to mark that as the answer to this question. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting digital audio to Midi notes requires a conversion tool. Some DAW's will have this built in, but otherwise a plugin can be sourced to do a similar job. This will allow musical notes played on an acoustic instrument to be converted into MIDI notes which can then be rendered  by a synthesiser or other electronic instrument.

Examples of this technology are "WIDI Recognition System" (https://www.widisoft.com/english/mp3-midi-products.html)

Answer (score 1):

When i knew nothing about anything i used an mp3-to-midi converter, and its output terrified me, because it makes every single sine harmonic into a midi note if it matches a note's frequency. Many harmonics don't align with any of the pitches in our 12-tone scale, so the program doesn't put them in, but a lot still make it through, resulting in a mess.

If you don't want to buy a specialized pedal you can try software audio-to-midi conversion, but only if you're willing to spend a while cleaning up both the recording and the output midi file. Noise cancellation in the original recording should do quite a bit, but it still won't reduce the guitar's timbre to a perfect sine.